# Dropbox api: how to save access token to reuse later?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropbox-api

I'm developing an application using Dropbox API and I want to let users browsing my files online.

Now, I need to save my access token and reuse to let users browser my Dropbox files online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit blurry, and I don't know Dropbox well, but I imagine that one way to store your access token would be to create a `config/initializers/dropbox.rb` file and store the token as a constant :

```
SomeCustomClass::ACCESS_TOKEN = 'kjhcsuhrovuhpvouhsojfklerkjnfolrivjspofivjsoih'.freeze
```

Now you can use the token from anywhere you want in your app by calling this constant.